# Steering Actuator Seek Near Sensor Transition

Tags: animation, game-engine, objects, logic-bricks

When an enemy senses a player with the near sensor and starts to seek the player with the steering actuator, is there a way to make the rotational transition smooth instead of instant?

Example: I walk up behind the enemy. I get close enough to trigger the near sensor. The enemy instantly turns around in 1 frame and begins seeking me.

I can't figure out how to make the enemy animation turn slowly towards me instead of instantly the moment it starts to seek.

Answer (score 0):

When the *Near* sensor is triggered the enemy will track to the player with an *Edit Object > Track to* actuator.

Add a *Ray* or *Radar* sensor to the enemy's camera or collision mesh with a player property in it, then connect it to the *Steering* actuator.

Comment: I tried to follow your answer but it is not very clear to me, can you put an image of the logic bricks?